# Gulp - Can gulp be used without node?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Is it possible to use 
**gulp without node**? 
The setup that requires - npm install -g gulp.
Is there a way to use gulp without using node?

Comment: no you cannot run gulp without node.. Because gulp is Node.js-based task runner. Gulp is a package of node and is needed in order to execute.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use gulp without node. Gulp is written in javascript and it runs with NodeJS.